# Open source alternative to Google authenticator app

Tags: ssh, authentication, android, google

I've set up Google authenticator as 2FA for ssh and it works great, but authenticator app for Android is not open source anymore. Is there a good real open source alternative?

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-authenticator still seems to be available.  Or are you talking about the cellphone app side?

Comment: this Q seems like a better fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JeffSchaller it maybe also fit for android se

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about the Unix-aspects of Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try FreeOTP, it supports both ​HOTP and ​TOTP.

https://freeotp.github.io/

https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.fedorahosted.freeotp/

Comment: How does it compare with andOTP?

Answer (score 2):

`Aegis authenticator` for Android is libre, simple and has useful features (import/export, biometric unlock, QR code scan or manual entry, material design...)

It is available on f-froid: https://f-droid.org/fr/packages/com.beemdevelopment.aegis/

Answer (score 0):

**AUTHY**.  Cloud-based, concurrent use from multiple devices, app is available for most modern platforms, including LINUX.  Compatible with Google Authenticator tokens.

I use it on my UBUNTU systems, mainly for login, su, and lightdm, although using PAM modules it will support many other protocols (sshd with public key, etc).

Here's a guide for configuring **2FA** on **UBUNTU JAMMY with PAM**:

GOOGLE AUTHENTICATOR ONLY FOR USERS CONFIGURED (~/.google_authenticator exists) (Tested Procedure)

Here are the steps for configuring PAM with Google Authenticator for the /etc/pam.d/login file. It will bypass the verification code if the user has not configured his/her token file.

Install the necessary packages for PAM and Google Authenticator using the following command:

`sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator`

Edit the /etc/pam.d/login file using a text editor:

`sudo nano /etc/pam.d/login`

Add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

`auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok`

Save the file and exit the text editor.

You can then repeat steps 2-3 for the /etc/pam.d/su and /etc/pam.d/lightdm files to complete the configuration.

For the ssh configuration adjust the ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes and UsePAM yes parameters. More information about other ssh parameters needed can be found at:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/enable-ssh-2fa-ubuntu-server/

SSH, 2FA, and Public Key Authentication

If the desired result is to skip 2FA with the Google Authenticator when invoking ssh with public key authentication, then the 'auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok' line must be placed at the end of /etc/pam.d/sshd. The file would look something like this:

@include common-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_key.so force revoke
@include common-session
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
session    optional     pam_mail.soenv # [1]
session    required     pam_limits.so
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
@include common-password
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok

To enforce 2FA for the root user even when public key authentication is used, you can modify the /etc/pam.d/sshd file by adding the auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok line after the @include common-auth line. This will ensure that the Google Authenticator PAM module is always called, even when public key is used. /etc/pam.d/sshd would look something like this:

@include common-auth
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
account    required     pam_nologin.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_key.so force revoke
@include common-session
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
session    optional     pam_mail.soenv # [1]
session    required     pam_limits.so
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
@include common-password

After making this change, restart the sshd service and try logging in as the root user again. You should now be prompted for the Google Authenticator verification code even when using public key authentication.

https://codeberg.org/kpiq/Tech-Space/wiki/2FA-Authenticator-app-%28any-compatible-with-Google-Authenticator%29-setup-for-Ubuntu-Jammy

This use case enables 2FA only for users with a valid ~/.google_authenticator file, that way you don't have to tune complex PAM settings.